# Getting 401 error on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-6, http-status-code-401

I run my asp.net web forms application with windows authentication on IIS 6.0 and there are following records in IIS logs:

```
2014-01-15 14:51:26 W3SVC1 192.168.21.16 GET /MyApp/myPage.aspx 80 - 192.168.128.19 ... 401 1 0
2014-01-15 14:51:26 W3SVC1 192.168.21.16 GET /MyApp/myPage.aspx 80 MyDomain\UserName 192.168.128.19 ... 200 0 0
```

So, request with no username (and 401 error as a result) is followed by request with username.
Such records with no username appear sometimes, not always. In the rest cases, there is a record with username only.

Please, can anyone tell me why I'm getting 401 error?

P.S. Anonymous athentication is disabled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have discovered how http auth works.

When a user first connects to a server the browser doesn't send any credentials. The reason being is that the browser doesn't know if it needs to. Nor does it know what format to send the password, and more importantly, YOU DON'T WANT TO SEND YOUR USERNAME PASSWORD TO EVERY SERVER YOU EVER VISIT.

So IIS receives this un-authenticated request, and sends back a 401. 401 doesn't just mean you are not authenticated to access this webpage, it also includes HOW you should authenticate (BASIC username/password, Kerberos etc to name a few methods).

TLDR. The 401 is to tell the browser how to send the username/password (and that you need to authenticate to view the resource).